# Populate ListView in Runtime in android

Tags: android

I am having a problem in UI. I have Two  edit text
fields on UI and 1 Add Button. And functionality of a button is to
take values from edit text fields and add them to list. The issue
which I am facing right now is that I don't know how to show that list
(List is not displayed when app UI shows for first time). And size of
list will increase as we add data in list.

Comment: Please show us, how do you use the adapter for listview.

Comment: Post the code you already have....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this. I haven´t tried the code, but I could be of some help.

```
private ListView lv;
private List<String> array= new ArrayList<String>();
private EditText et1;
private EditText et2;


    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
         setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

         lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list_view_id);

         et1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_edittext1_id);

         et2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_edittext2_id);


    }


private void onClick(View v){
    String v1=et1.getText().toString();
    String v2=et2.getText().toString();
    array.add(v1);
    array.add(v2);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                 this, 
                 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                 array);

         lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 
}
```

For the size of the list maybe you should check the possibility of including scrollbars